# Trying to log into site with scrapy and response shows login page

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I'm new to Scrapy and I'm trying to get a log in working, starting in the shell. This is the site I'm trying to log into:

https://www.acdd.com/customer/account/login/

First I did

`from scrapy.http import FormRequest`

and then I did

`token = response.xpath('//*[@name="form_key"]/@value').extract_first()` to get the token and the output looks correct. I then did

`FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'form_key': token,'login[customerid]': '12345','login[username]': 'myaddress@email.com','login[password]': 'mysecret'})`

It outputs

`<GET https://www.acdd.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=&login%5Bcustomerid%5D=12345&login%5Busername%5D=myaddress%40email.com&login%5Bpassword%5D=mysecret&form_key=abcdef12345>`

If I do `view(response)` it just shows the login page and not the user page like it should. I've been following tutorials and examples but I think maybe there is just something different about this site than the simple examples I've used. I logged in with Firefox and looked in the developer tools to see what form data it POST and I have all the elements. It also looks like while the form is on `https://www.acdd.com/customer/account/login/`, it actually posts to `https://www.acdd.com/customer/account/login/Post`. I've tried to just post to that page in the shell but there are no form elements. This is outside the basic examples I've worked with. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't select target form and Scrapy uses the first one on the page (search form):

```
FormRequest.from_response(
    response=response,
    formid="login-form",
    formdata={
        'login[customerid]': '12345',
        'login[username]': 'myaddress@email.com',
        'login[password]': 'mysecret',
        'send': "",
    }
)
```

Also you don't need `form_key` here because Scrapy will get it from a form for you.
**UPDATE** Try to add `send` key.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense now, thanks. After a while I kind of realized there was some other element at play but I could figure out how to get to it. Is getting the form key automatically a new thing? I was following the examples that said to do it that way. 

I now get the proper response `<POST https://www.acdd.com/customer/account/loginPost/>` but when I try to view the output with `view(response)` or `open_in_browser(response)` (what's the difference between the two?) it still shows the login page instead of the account page. I didn't turn off redirects or anything.

Comment: I did try adding `send` with the same result. It is supposed to redirect me to `https://www.acdd.com/customer/account/` after login. I do get `<POST https://www.acdd.com/customer/account/loginPost/>` as output now but `view(response)` still shows the login page.

Comment: Well, it looks like my spider code work fine and the page redirects properly. It doesn't seem to work when I test in the shell but I guess that's ok for now. I'm sure I'll figure that out as I get more experienced. Thanks.